# Not recognized due to async when switching to the Blazor page

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is the case when you switch from the page you use async to another page and come back. When I return, async is constantly working on the console and data is coming in, but `StateHasChanged()` does not seem to be able to update the screen even if it is working or not. Is there a problem that the page cannot be updated normally due to the problem of separating threads? (`StateHasChanged()` and other functions) In this case, how can I make the existing thread that I want to recognize?

I searched and there was a word about `Synchronization Context`, would this help?

```
@page "/push"

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@subscribe">subscribe</button>
<div>
  @foreach (var noti in PushNotifications.notifications)
  {
    <p>@noti</p>
  }
</div>

@code {
public async Task subscribe()
{
...
    reply = client.subscribe(subscriptionRequest);

    try
    {
      await foreach (var subscriptionResponse in reply.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(subscriptionResponse);
        PushNotifications.notifications.Add(subscriptionResponse);

        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        await Task.Delay(500);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the method where this code is called?

Comment: @JesseGood Thank you for your interest. I added the code.
The function is called through the buttons on the same page. The omitted part of the function has the action of subscribing to the server and is answered in the form of gRPC stream. I want to update this inside <div> through StateHasChanged, but UI update does not work after switching pages.

Comment: I'm assuming your loop is slow retrieving data, so is the intent to display a line at a time as it comes in?  You can't switch to another page and come back to this one and preserve state.  On the return to this page you will be creating a new instance of the component.  If the old page hasn't completed then it will still be using resources the nee one needs.  To maintain state you need to move all the data retrieval to a scoped service and plug your UI into that service.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That meant this page now using asnyc. This issue does not work when switched to another page and returned to this page. I solved the problem in a different way in the previous question, but I still wonder why this method doesn't work.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, that's the intention. I understood to some extent why not through your answers. ```RepeatedField<CreateTopic> createTopics = new RepeatedField<CreateTopic>();``` I created an instance where I put data in the @code part of the page in this way, and does this mean that it will be newly created when the page is switched? I used to think that this would be maintained even if the page was switched.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis However, even if you switch to a different page and return, the contents of the existing instance are printed on the screen and cannot be updated in real time, and if an event such as clicking a button occurs, it can be updated. I saw this and thought the instance was maintained. I implemented the installer through the code above and the service registration through AddSingleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that demonstrates one way to maintain state between pages with a long running process.

Everything takes place in a DI scoped service.  In this case it just gets a list of countries slowly.  There's two cancellation mechanisms: a cancellation token or a method to set an bool.

```cs
public class DataService
{
    public List<string> Countries { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public Action? CountryListUpdated;
    public bool Processing { get; private set; }=false;
    private bool _cancel = false;
    private CancellationToken _cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    private Task? _task;
    public string Message { get; private set; } = "Idle";

    public ValueTask GetCountriesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        _task = this.getCountriesAsync();
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public ValueTask GetCountriesAsync()
    {
        _task = this.getCountriesAsync();
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task getCountriesAsync()
    {
        this.Processing = true;
        this.Message = "Processing";
        this.Countries.Clear();
        foreach (var country in _countries)
        {
            this.Countries.Add(country);
            this.CountryListUpdated?.Invoke();
            await Task.Delay(2500);
            if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested || _cancel)
                Debug.WriteLine("GetCountries Cancelled");

        }
        this.Message = "Processing Complete";
        this.Processing = false;
        _cancel = false;
        this.CountryListUpdated?.Invoke();
    }

    public void CancelProcessing()
        => _cancel = true;

    private List<string> _countries => new List<string> { "UK", "France", "Portugal", "Spain", "Italy", "Germany"};
   
}
```

Registered in Program:

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService>();
```

Here's the display page.  Note UI updates are event driven.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject DataService DataService;
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" disabled="@(!this.DataService.Processing)" @onclick=this.CancelProcessing>Cancel Processing</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@this.DataService.Processing" @onclick=GetData>Get Data</button>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-primary">@this.DataService.Message</div>

@foreach (var country in DataService.Countries)
{
    <div>@country</div>
}


@code {
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.DataService.CountryListUpdated += OnCountryUpdated;

    private async Task GetData()
    {
        await this.DataService.GetCountriesAsync(cancellationToken.Token);
    }

    private void CancelProcessing()
    {
        //DataService.CancelProcessing();
        this.cancellationToken.Cancel();
    }

    private void OnCountryUpdated()
        => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // If you want to cancel the processing when you exit a page
        //cancellationToken.Cancel();
        this.DataService.CountryListUpdated -= OnCountryUpdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been resolved using that method. I still have questions about why my method doesn't work, but I've certainly learned how to organize pages with long execution processes. I didn't know about Action, so I'll take this opportunity to learn more about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ... you use async to another page and come back. When I return, async is constantly working on the console [...] , but StateHasChanged() does not seem to be able to update the screen

The most likely explanation is that you 'return' to a new page but the console is still displaying incoming data on the previous old page.
That page is still in memory but not on screen. It should have been cleaned up.

Step 1: When your page code creates resources (like HttpClient) then you need:

```
@implements IDisposable

@code {
  ...
  
  public void Dispose() 
  { 
     // Dispose resources, make sure your subscription loop is canceled. 
     _httpClient?.Dispose();
     ... 
  } 
}
```

> I searched and there was a word about Synchronization Context, would this help?

No, when running on WebAssembly that context is `null`.

Comment: "you 'return' to a new page" I've had this thought before. However, I don't understand that the update will be made at the time of an event such as clicking a button after switching pages. it doesn't make sense, If you click on it, you can see the previous page, and if it stays there, the new page will continue to appear.